# Una web a base ajax no está permitiendo a google indexar contenido

Tags: html, posicionamiento

Estoy haciendo una web

Quería que se sintiese como una aplicación al navegar desde moviles y toda la navegación y la carga de contenido depende de javascript

Cargo todas las secciones en la primera carga y a partir de ahi voy mostrando y ocultando la sección que corresponda cargando el contenido mediante ajax y google no está indexando nada.

Es como una web de anuncios, si todas las páginas se generasen en el servidor, google podría obtener toda la lista de anuncios y cada página de anuncio de manera independiente

Pero como esa lista y las páginas de los anuncios las genero a base de ajax, google no está indexando absolutamente nada

Como puedo hacer que google sea capaz de seguir los enlaces de la página?

La única idea que tengo es duplicar el trabajo por asi decirlo, en la primera carga generar la web en el lado servidor solo con la sección correspondiente y su contenido, una vez la página ha terminado de cargar, entonces cargar todo el resto de secciones por ajax y a partir de ahi seguir con javascript para la navegación.

Eso permitiria a google navegar a través de los enlaces pero siento que estoy duplicando el trabajo y no se si esa es la forma de hacerlo

Comment: No es necesario poner la dirección de tu web para lo que preguntas, y mucha gente se lo toma a mal porque da la sensación de que se esté intentando aprovechar de SOes para mejorar el SEO de la página. Intenta evitarlo a no ser que sea necesario para poder entender el problema. En este caso, acceder a la web no nos proporciona ninguna información que no hayas descrito ya en la pregunta por lo cual puede obviarse. Además, si en el futuro tu página deja de existir y la pregunta depende de ella, la pregunta quedaría inútil! Es mejor que las preguntas sean autocontenidas siempre que se pueda :)

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Qué es lo que *le sienta fatal a Google* exactamente? ¿Qué problemas o errores hay? Al inspeccionar la URL que nos muestras aparecen varios errores 404 por ejemplo y es algo que deberías resolver en primer término.

Comment: disculpa pero no se entiende absolutamente nada tu problema

Comment: ya he editado la pregunta, a ver si así consigo explicarme un poquito mejor 

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: si es ajax, es la misma url.. porque pensas que google va a navegar la misma url una y otra vez?

Comment: las url son funcionales, cada seccion, cada listado, cada anuncio... tiene su url única y en la web los enlaces están hechos con etiquetas "a" pero al cargar el contenido por javascript no lo lee

Comment: Efectivamente, tu problema es el Ajax y la indexación de contenido. No es menos cierto que Google ha mejorado por mucho la indexación de páginas que se cargan vía Ajax, perooooo tendrías que hacer una revisión de tu código, tal vez no cumpla con determinadas pautas o no haya tenido en cuenta las limitaciones que pueda tener el bot de Google encargado de eso. Son disímiles los problemas que puedas tener tu código. Investiga al respecto.